# Testing if nodes are visible to each other?

Tags: erlang, elixir

How would I check if my deployed nodes can see each other?
I tried to do:

```
mix edeliver ping production --verbose
```

I got:

```
EDELIVER MY_IDEA WITH PING COMMAND

-----> pinging production servers



production node: 0

  user    : bitnami
  host    : xxx
  path    : /home/bitnami
  response: pong

production node: 1

  user    : bitnami
  host    : yyy
  path    : /home/bitnami
  response: pong
```

My app is deployed to:

```
~/my_idea/releases/0.0.1
```

I know this can be achieved in elixir via command line, using erlang `Nodes().` ? But how to run the console as attached to the running app scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your looking for is a remote shell. In Erlang I would typically use `erl` to connect to a remote node:

```
erl -sname $short_name -setcookie $erlang_cookie -hidden -remsh $remote_node
```

Of course replace `$short_name` with a name of your chosing and `$erlang_cookie` the cookie value of the node you want to connect to (`$remote_node`).

In your case I would just do something like this:

```
# Replace `node0` with the exact node name
erl -sname foobar -setcookie yourcookie -hidden -remsh node0 
# Once in the shell run:
1> net_adm:ping(node1). % Replace with the node name of the other node
```

If you get `pong` the nodes can communicate. If you get `pang` the nodes are unable to communicate. You can also try running `nodes()` to get a list of connected nodes.

Note that nodes don't connect until they have to, so if they haven't sent any messages to each other you will get an empty list. A successful call to `net_adm:ping/1` will cause a node to be in the list returned by `nodes/0`.

Refer to the documentation on [Distributed Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) for more details.